# mysql_num_rows in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, mysql-num-rows

im trying to make an option for an admin, to choose in which order to show the categories in the website.

so in the control panel, he has an up arrow and a down arrow next to each category's title. if he clicks down, the category goes down in one order.

my problam is, if the category is at the bottom, last in the order, and the admin clicks on the down arrow, i want to show an error.

so i did something like this on my controller:

```
    /*
 * Category order - down
 */
public function down($id)
{

    $cat = Cat::findOrFail($id);

    $new_location = $cat->location + 1;

    $num_cats = count(Cat::all()); //number of cats
    //die($num_cats);
    if ($new_location >= $num_cats)
    {
        return Redirect::route('pages')->with('msg', 'it is allready the last category');
    }

    $cat->where('location', '=', $new_location)->update(['location' => $cat->location]); //moving the old category
    $cat->where('id', '=', $id)->update(['location' => $new_location]); //updating the new location

    return Redirect::route('pages')->with('msg', 'the cat has been updated');
}
```

but $num_cats turns to be null.

any ideas how can i fetch the number of all my categories?

EDIT: Model

```
class Cat extends Model { 
    public $timestamps = false; 
    protected $fillable = array( 'name', 'location', 'slug' ); 

    /*
     * A categorey has many pages 
     */ 
    public function pages() { 
        return $this->hasMany('App\Page')->where('solo', '!=', 1); 
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: The collection that of which is returned from the all method, has a count method on it. `Cat::all()->count()`

Comment: i changed it and still returns null.

Comment: Is there any results returned from your all()? You could try `Cat::get()->count()`, same thing just using get instead.

Comment: still nothing... i added: <code>die($num_cats)</code> to see what i get, and i only see a blank page. so i tried <code>die(print_r($num_cats))</code> and now i get the number 31, though there are only 3 categories.

Comment: Include your model code.

Comment: edit: aww how can i wrap it as code? sory.. <code>class Cat extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = array(
        'name',
        'location',
        'slug'
    );

    /*
     * A categorey has many pages
     */
    public function pages() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Page')->where('solo', '!=', 1);
    }

}</code>

Comment: Easier to edit the question with it.

Comment: What is the result of your `Cat::all()` do you get each of the categories models within a collection?

Comment: this is the print_r(Cat::all()): `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => App\Cat Object ( [timestamps] => [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => location [2] => slug ) [connection:protected] ..... ) 1`

Comment: Try changing the extends to `Eloquent` instead of `Model`.

Comment: now i get this: `FatalErrorException in Cat.php line 5:
Class 'App\Eloquent' not found` so i added: `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` but still doesn't work

Comment: Add a `\ ` like so `extends \Eloquent`

Comment: no error but still returns null

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you do ***count*** like this`$num_cats = Cat::count()`;

Because the return of `Cat::all()`  is an object of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`

You need to know the function count

`int count ( mixed $array_or_countable [, int $mode = COUNT_NORMAL ] )`

AND

`Cat::count();` SQL: `SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM "cats"`; Need less memory.

`Cat::all()->count();` SQL: `SELECT * FROM "cats";` Need more memory.

Comment: not working so i tried

`$num_cats = Cat::all()->items;`

and i get this error:
`Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$items`

Comment: @amf oh, sorry. `items` is a protected property, `Collection::all()` will return it. Look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L15-L54). If you want get the count ONLY, please use `$num_cats = Cat::count()`.

Comment: so it's the same problem i had... it returns a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of this to get counts:

```
$num_cats = count(Cat::all());
```

or

```
$num_cats = Cat::all()->count();
```

or

```
$num_cats = count(Cat::all()->toArray());
```